# Deadlocks using wait and notify

Tags: java, deadlock

I am trying to understand how deadlocks are created. I've understood that by using two threads on two synchronized methods, a deadlock can be created. 
Went through many examples from the net.

Can a deadlock be created with wait and notify? 
Every time a thread is on wait, it will be notified. So how does this end up in a deadlock?

Illustration of an example will be helpful.

Comment: One of many, many examples and explainations: http://javarevisited.blogspot.cz/2010/10/what-is-deadlock-in-java-how-to-fix-it.html

Answer (score 4):

```
Deadlock is caused when two threads try to obtain the same, multiple locks in different order:

    // T1
    synchronized (A) {
      synchronized (B) {
        // ...
      }
    }

    // T2
    synchronized (B) {
      synchronized (A) {
        // ...
      }

}
```

The only way to prevent deadlocks is to make sure that all threads obtain locks in the same order--either they all do A then B, or they all do B then A.

If you don't have multiple locks, then you don't have a deadlock. However, you can get thread starvation or other things that may look similar to deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

A thread which is on wait will not be notified unless some code explicitly notifies it. Therefore the example you are looking for is absolutely trivial:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   synchronized(String.class) {
       String.class.wait();
   }
}
```

and this hangs forever. Technically, though, it is not a deadlock, which requires two or more threads involved in a closed cycle where each thread waits for the next one to unblock it.

Comment: It would be nice if the JVM, in the case that no progress can be made, would raise some Exception in one of the blocked threads.

Comment: @Ingo Why should it be the JVM's job to cure bad programming?

Comment: @b1nary.atr0phy would you call a NullPointerException a cure for bad programing? No, it's just diagnosis of a problem, and this is the JVM's job.

Comment: @Ingo Apples and oranges. Should the JVM be detecting whether you wanted to --x instead of x++ too?

Comment: @b1nary.atr0phy On the flip side, why should the JVM be detecting a null pointer or out-of-memory? Answer: because 1) it can, and 2) it makes our life easier.

Comment: You are trying to compare one type of operation, a simple true or false scenario (is x null or not?) with another that is incredibly complex. E.g. Reentrant locks support over 2 billion recursive locks on a single thread. Detection isn't a trivial ordeal. It would require the JVM to poll for deadlocks every single time a thread fails to lock a mutex. Many programmers would find it unacceptably expensive. Then you'd also have to deal with cost variance between different JVMs, due to the differences in thread scheduling.

Comment: @b1nary.atr0phy First of all, this is a completely new line of argument compared to your earlier comments. Second,  `It would require the JVM to poll for deadlocks every single time a thread fails to lock a mutex.`---I really don't see the reason why this statement would be true. A lazy, low-overhead mechanism could occasionally check for deadlock conditions. Nobody mentioned a fail-fast detection mechanism.

Comment: [Redirected the discussion to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84258/discussion-between-marko-topolnik-and-b1nary-atr0phy).

Answer (score 1):

Say thread 1 enters a synchronized block on method A and then waits. Thread 2 then attempts to enter the synchronized block on method A. Thread 1 is waiting for a notify, and thread 2 is waiting on the synchronized block. Everything is now waiting. Some other thread will have to notify the object on which thread 1 is waiting. This is just one scenario that can create a deadlock. There are all kinds of ways to do it.

Comment: Quoting `Object#wait` javadoc: "The thread releases ownership of this monitor and waits [...]"

Answer (score 0):

Something close to wait/notify deadlock:

```
public class Example
{
    volatile boolean isNotified = false;

    public synchronized void method1() {
        try
        {
            isNotified = false;
            while (!isNotified)
                wait();
            notifyAll();
            System.out.println("Method 1");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {/*NOP*/}
    }

    public synchronized void method2() {
        try {
            isNotified = true;
            while (isNotified)
                wait();
            notifyAll();

            System.out.println("Method 2");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {/*NOP*/}

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Example example = new Example();

        Thread thread1 = new Thread()
        {

            public void run()
            {
                example.method1();
            }
        };

        Thread thread2 = new Thread()
        {

            public void run()
            {
                example.method2();
            }
        };

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: how would this create a deadlock?